# Java using Runtime Exec to execute Terminal Command

Tags: java, youtube-dl

So I use youtube-dl with homebrew in terminal to download videos and songs off youtube, but I do it a lot so I wanted to make a small java program to do it for me. This is what I have:

```
// Read ouput
public static void readOutput(Process proc) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    // Read the output
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    String line = "";
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.print(line + "\n");
    }

    proc.waitFor(); 
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    
    String command = "youtube-dl --version";
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, new File("/Users"));
    
    readOutput(proc);
    
    
}
```

Right now I'm just trying to get it to recognize youtube-dl because it keeps giving this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "youtube-dl" (in directory "/Users"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

I figure this is because on M1 mac homebrew packages install to /opt/homebrew/bin and so I had to add that path into my terminal current directory (/etc/paths) to be able to use it, but when using the Runtime exec command with the given directory as an argument it never finds youtube-dl. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You could query `/etc/paths` or explicitely specify the path of youtube-dl

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the full path to the executable file. Also use class [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) rather than class `Runtime`.

For simply printing the text output of the command, just inherit standard I/O

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/opt/homebrew/bin/youtube-dl",
                                       "--version");
pb.inheritIO();
Process p = pb.start();
int result = p.waitFor();
```

The output of the command will be written to `System.out`.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it working using runtime and specifying the paths to youtube-dl and ffmpeg